# ReactJs - Fetch a quote every 5 seconds with axios and display it in the <p>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

I am new to Reactjs programming and I have a component which uses Grid of react bootstrap.

I want to fetch a quoute from some public API every 5 seconds and display it in the

inside the Grid. I also want to use axios for fetching the quote. Any tutorial or any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: We'd like to help you, but this question is very broad. Please include what you have tried so far, and read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like the following.

You should use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to make the fetch request. You can also use `setInterval` there too to trigger the api request every 5 seconds (5000 ms). In the `componentWillUnmount` section you should clear the interval.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    joke: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getJoke();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getJoke();
    }, 5000);
  }

  getJoke() {
    fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          joke: res.value
        });
      });
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
 }

  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.joke}</p>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```